# Maven Build using 1.3 Error

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu

I am trying to build my java application and getting compilation error as below :

```
[ERROR] /media/disk2/myapp/assignment/src/main/java/helper/HelperFunctions.java:[29,16] error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
```

But java i am using is 1.7 version, I am using ubuntu14.04 on my mechine. Any idea how to solve this.

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_76"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_76-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.76-b04, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Check the compiler plugin settings; the error message says that the compiler is using 1.3 as a source version, which is not what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the below tag in your pom.xml

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <!-- or whatever version you use -->
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```